# binary operator cannot be applied to two 'NSWindowStyleMask' operands

Tags: swift, macos

I was trying to edit a timer app, and this line of code came up. How should i fix it?

```
let styleMask: Int = NSClosableWindowMask | NSTitledWindowMask
```

The error was:

> binary operator | cannot be applied to two 'NSWindowStyleMask'
>   operands.

Answer (score 1):

These are `Int`s in ObjC but in Swift, they are imported as option set:

```
let styleMask: NSWindowStyleMask = [.closable, .titled]
```